# Rails : not routing properly, redirect back to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, hyperlink

I have a page on the website, which has lots of anchor link eg `#menu` | `#sauces` etc

On the page itself the links work fine, its brilliant. 
However when I am on a different controller/view, The links do not take me back to the main controller, and to the anchor point clicked.

here is an example of one anchor link, which is in the header (which is on ALL controller views)

> ```
>     <%= link_to '#main', :id => 'menu_link' do %>
>     <li>Menu</li>
>     <% end %>
> ```

That is in `:controller => "main", :action => "index"`

When I am in another controller, for example my locations controller,
The links become like this `localhost:3000/locations#menu`

It should really be `localhost:3000/#menu`

The root is set to go to the main controller and index action.

Here is my routes.rb file

> ```
>  root :to => "main#index"
>    match 'admin', :to => 'access#admin_index'
>    match 'locations', :to => 'ranch_locations#locations'
>    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that it is going to a different controller.

```
<%= link_to '#main', :controller => "main", :action => "index", :id => 'menu_link' do %>
  <li>Menu</li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `root_path(:anchor => :main)` instead of `"#main"`

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

**upd:**

```
<%= link_to '#main', :id => 'menu_link' do %>
```

should be changed to

```
<%= link_to root_path(:anchor => :main), :id => 'menu_link' do %>
```

Comment: I dont understand at all. Would it be possible to show an example specific to my question?

Comment: The URL is proper now, how it should be, however the link, when clicked does not do anything, it does not get redirected correctly. when i do open with new tab it works, when I click it doesn't?

Comment: When you use `"#main"` this anchor just attaches to **current** url. Whats why you were stay at same page.

Comment: my anchors do not work anymore on the main page. And still like I said, when I click the links, the link does not work, only the URL is correct.